Flask-MySQL Python long request
I'm using Flask to create an API. I need to make a query to the database and for this I used the flask_mysqldb library
The fact is that before that I used another library (mysql.connector) and my queries worked much faster, about 2-3 times.
I have a question, what could be the reason? The request doesn't change, I just change the library
I took measurements and in the end, it seems to me that there is a long delay during the cursor declaration (cur = mysql.connection.cursor()).
It seems to me that every time I declare a cursor, I have a re-connection to the database and because of this there is a delay
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

application.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = CONNECT_HOST
application.config['MYSQL_USER'] = CONNECT_USER
application.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = CONNECT_PASSWORD
application.config['MYSQL_DB'] = CONNECT_DB

mysql = MySQL(application)

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userId` = %s", (userId,))
mysql.connection.commit()
cur.close()

